# Translation matrices exercices [ check my answer please ]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $L:R^2 \to R^3$ be linear transformation with equation:
$L((x_1,x_2)^T) = (x_2,\ x_1 + x_2,\ x_1 - x_2)^T$
Let:
$ u_1 = (1,2)^T, u_2 = (3,1)^T $ and $b_1 = (1,0,0)^T, b_2 = (1,1,0)^T, b_3 = (1,1,1)^T $
Then 
$  \mu := \{u_1, u_2\}$ is $R^2$ basis , and $\beta := \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is $R^3$ basis 
Let also $\varepsilon$ be standart basis in $R^3$.
(a) Find $m_{\mu\varepsilon}(L)$( matrix $L$ in base $\mu$ and $\varepsilon$ )
(b) Find translation matrix from basis $\beta$ to basis $\varepsilon$ ( $m_{\beta\varepsilon}(id)$ )
(c) Find translation matrix from basis $\varepsilon$ to basis $\beta$ ( $m_{\varepsilon\beta}(id)$ ) 
(d) Using (a) and (c), designate $m_{\mu\beta}(L)$

It's one of previous year exam exercises but I've no idea how to do it. I am willing to learn though, so if anyone could help me get what to do here or send me link to a good video tutorial or article explaining how to solve it or just explained me it here and maybe solved if it's not that hard it would be great.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j5WnqwMdCk

Answer (score 1):

Ok I made my research and I (don't)think this is correct solution:
To find transformation matrix in standard basis we take Indentity matrix and multiply by our transformation, so $L(1,0)^T = (0,1,1)^T$
 $L(0,1)^T = (1,1,-1)^T$ 
$L = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&1\\1&-1\end{array}\right]$ in standard basis $\varepsilon$ 
$\mu = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&3\\2&1\end{array}\right]$
$\beta = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$
So $m_{\mu\varepsilon}(L) $ is Linear transformation matrix from $\mu$ coordinates to $\varepsilon$ coordinates if I understand right.
So i have to multiply by $\mu L $, by $\mu$ to get standard $R^2$ coordinates and then apply $L$ to get in $R^3$ standard coordinates. But u apply $L\vec{x}$ so $m_{\mu\varepsilon}(L) =  L \mu $?

(b) I have something in $\beta$ means I have $\beta^{-1}\vec{x}$ so I simply multiply by $\beta$?

(c) I have in standard so I simply multiply by $\beta^{-1}$ and voila?

(d) $m_{\mu\beta}(L) =\beta^{-1} L \mu  $

I don't believe myself. If this was so simple someone would reply before :S Could you tell me if it's OK?